# How to include a variable in an html request?

Tags: html, mysql, gwt

I can't figure out the syntax for using a variable in a html request as opposed to a static value. For example, I have :

`CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();`

`HttpGet request = new HttpGet("someDatabaseAdress/getUser?id=1");`

but when I try:

`Int userId = 1;`

`CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();`

`HttpGet request = new HttpGet("someDatabaseAdress/getUser?id=userId");`

I get a build error. The query is going out a mysql table with an integer value in the queried parameter.
Does anyone know if the syntax I'm using is correct? Or is there perhaps a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything within the quotes is treated as a string, so here it tries to make the id value (which should be an int) the string "userId".

HttpGet request = new HttpGet("someDatabaseAdress/getUser?id=" + userId);

should fix it by adding the value itself rather than its name to the string.